# I'm looking for a word similar to correlate/to reasonate with

Tags: single-word-requests

Priding myself in being able to say precisely what I mean I have hit a stumbling block. I'm trying to describe a lack of alignment between an emotional state and knowledge of something where my knowledge invalidates my emotional state. One could say they did not correlate or did not resonate with one another but neither of those are really quite right.

I'm looking for word that when used in a positive context implies that two things or ideas not only correlate but conform to each other and mesh well together. When the word itself used is in a negative context it implies a breakdown in the system if the two things are not working together.

I know the word exists and I believe it starts with a C but after 2 weeks of trying to use Google and a friend of mine who is an English major I am still at an impasse.

The sentence I most recently tried to use was as follows. "I realized something was wrong when I found my internal emotional reaction over your comment did not _____ with my knowledge of who you are."

Answer (score 2):

Try *comport*:

> *I realized something was wrong when I found my internal emotional reaction over your comment did not **comport** with my knowledge of
> who you are.*

From the *OED*:

> **comport**, *v.*
> **5.** intr. ***to comport with***: to agree with, accord with; to suit, befit.

Here’s the last of the sample usages offered there:

> <sub>1884     T. SPEEDY *Sport in Highlands* xvi. 288
>    Such wholesale slaughter does not comport with our
> opinion as to what really constitutes sport.</sub>

<sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>